# Statically build external library with MEX files

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, opencv, mex

I downloaded source code of OpenCV and built statically (no DLL option) by Visual Studio (in release mode) so that I can create standalone executables. It works perfectly fine with Visual Studio in release mode with \MT flag (runtime library : Multi-threaded). Note that I have errors if I compile\link in debug mode or change \MT flag such as \MD: Multi-threaded DLL)

Now, I want to use it with MEX. I changed \MD with \MT in mex specifications(mexopt.bat file) and mex compiles\links without any error. However, when I execute MEX function, it breaks MATLAB and shows error message: "Segmentation violation detected".

I utilized OpenCV with MEX functions before. But, It was a dynamic compilation.

I think I can solve this problem, if I modify Visual Studio compiler\linker flags in mexopt.bat file.

Can you help me ?

Comment: I realized that the problem is related with std::vector usage in the code. When I drop /D_SECURE_SCL=0 flag in mex specifications(mexopt.bat file), it works fine.